# Compiling SQL Archive Tool

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, archive

I am using SQLite database and I want to archive database by using SQL Archive Tool (SQLAR) but i don't know how to compile. I found only this document which is given below. Could you help me to compile and use SQLAR Tool to use it ?

https://www.sqlite.org/sqlar/tree?ci=trunk&expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After these steps are done, i can compress the database.

- Download source files. (https://www.sqlite.org/sqlar/vinfo?name=15adeb2f9a1b0b8c)
- Copy files to your server.
- Write "make" command in your sqlar path which includes source files.
- Write command "./sqlar archive_name database_name" to archive your database.